# An anime that starts with two paramedics driving an ambulance who got killed by a young person with mechanical claws out of their fingers

Tags: story-identification, anime

So, I was at my grandfather's house when I was 10 and he left me alone for like 30 minutes to go mow his lawn.

And I saw this clip of an anime that started with two paramedics driving an ambulance. There was a young-ish person in the back, unconscious. Then the person twitches, mechanical claws come out of their fingers and they kill both paramedics.

I don't remember anything other than that because my grandfather came back after and switched it to *Clarence* or something because it had blood in it. It's not *Ghost in the Shell* though, I already checked that.

Comment: The image at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kemonozume doesn't look familiar to you? I haven't found any evidence that there are paramedics in an ambulance, but the general idea of people manifesting claws fits.